# Keyboard and Touchpad not working on ASUS notebook Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, hardware-failure, asus-laptop

The full story can be found on [my post here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-system/windows-8-not-responding-at-welcome-screen-and/059fac31-67f0-44bd-ba50-b95d91b8b3ec?tm=1432084826572)

To sum up:

- The built in keyboard and touch pad does not function. I can only use external device(USB keyboard and mouse).
- Soon after successfully logged into Windows, I got **WORKER_INVALID** error message and windows forced me to restart. The message disappeared once I uninstalled ASUS Smart Gesture driver.
- The newest driver for ASUS (ASUS Smart Gesture and ASUS ATK Package driver) does not solve this. I could even adjust settings for touchpad in ASUS Smart Gesture panel, yet my touchpad did not response.
- Even stranger, when I opened the computer, I can use my keyboard and even type in the Linux grub shell. **But once system got loaded, both in Windows and LinuxMint, the keyboard and touchpad stop functioning.**

Now I suspect my BIOS went wrong, but I am not sure and dare not update the BIOS so rashly. May anyone suggest anything?

---

Update:
At last I went to the repair center and got the notebook repaired. It was a hardware failure but the people there did not explain much to me.

Comment: "The message disappeared once I uninstalled ASUS Smart Gesture driver." you've already posted the solution. Kill the driver and be happy. Contact the ASUS support for a fixed version and if they produce the fixed driver, install the fixed version.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Maybe I should change the title for this post. I realised that even if I solved the WORKER_INVALID error, the keyboard and touchpad did not function. I have tested in both OS and none worked. I reasoned that since the LinuxMint System should not be affected my Windows OS (hence problem beside the windows driver should exist), the hardware must be the fault. But weird thing is that I tested my keyboard on grub shell and it worked! It seems that loading the system kill the keyboard.

Comment: have you contacted the ASUS support for the keyboard issues?

Comment: Yes I have. But they don't seem to understand my problem. I am planing to send my notebook to support centre for diagnose.

Comment: this is a good idea. If the keyboard doesn't work in Linux and Windows it looks like a hardware issue.